# What is an English adjective that means "able to learn new things quickly"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an English adjective to describe the following skill: "able to learn new things quickly"?

For example:

> Billy is very _________, as he learns new skills more quickly than an average person.

Comment: "able to learn new things quickly" == "learns quickly"

Comment: "Quick study" is probably the best short phrase for this.

Comment: "fast learner" may help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Fast learner* or *quick learner*

Comment: +1 They're not the snappy single word that I suspect the OP wants, but they are IMHO the most accurate phrase. An other single word is a compromise IMHO.

Comment: "Quick study" would refer to a person who readily acquires both skills and knowledge, but with a clear inclusion of becoming knowledgeable as well as skillful.

Answer (score 21):

I would say *clever*, *quick-witted* or, informally, *smart*:

> [image]
>   **[clever](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0154580)** (adjective)
>   quick to understand, learn, and devise or apply ideas; intelligent.
>
> ---
>
> **[quick-witted](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0680650)** (adjective)
>   showing or characterized by an ability to think or respond quickly or effectively.

Comment: Why informally?  That's what smart means.

Comment: @Kevin mostly because this meaning of smart is marked as informal in the *New Oxford American Dictionary*…

Comment: I think only in certain contexts would those words be acceptable for "able to learn new things quickly".  For example, someone that was quickly able to learn how to garden or take care of the elderly wouldn't usually be called "clever" but a "fast learner".

Answer (score 18):

here are some words that came to mind - [sagacious](http://www.wordnik.com/words/sagacious),

> Exhibiting or marked by keen
> intellectual discernment, especially
> of human motives and actions; having
> or proceeding from penetration into
> practical affairs in general; having
> keen practical sense; acute in
> discernment or penetration; discerning
> and judicious; shrewd: as, a sagacious
> mind.

there's [astute](http://www.wordnik.com/words/astute),

> Quick at seeing how to gain advantage,
> especially for oneself; shrewd;
> critically discerning.

and of course, [polymathic](http://www.wordnik.com/words/polymathic)

> Pertaining to polymathy; acquainted
> with many branches of learning.

and [autodidactic](http://www.wordnik.com/words/autodidactic) :)

> Relating to or having the characteristics of an autodidact; self-taught.

Answer (score 8):

> **[Sponge](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sponge)** -
>   a person or thing that absorbs something freely: 
>   *His mind is a sponge gathering historical data.*

Comment: Or, perhaps dependent on delivery and context, sponge could mean a complete absence of anything resembling a centre of thought, in reference to the animal!

Comment: @Sam, I have just the [therapy](https://youtu.be/0lQl-oVig3w) for you.

Answer (score 7):

The idiom "[quick on the uptake](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/quick+on+the+uptake)" would apply here.

> Defintion: quick to understand or learn
>   something.
>
> Example: Just because I'm not quick on the
>   uptake, it doesn't mean I'm stupid.
>   Mary understands jokes before anyone
>   else because she's so quick on the
>   uptake.

Answer (score 7):

I have often heard *sharp* used in this context.

> mentally acute; clever; astute

Synonym discussion:

> **intelligent**, quick  have varying implications. Sharp  suggests an acute, sensitive, alert, penetrating quality: a sharp mind. Keen  implies observant, incisive, and vigorous: a keen intellect. Intelligent  means not only acute, alert, and active, but also able to reason and understand: an intelligent reader. *Quick  suggests lively and rapid comprehension, prompt response to instruction, and the like: quick at figures*.

Answer (score 7):

I think idioms like 'quick study', 'quick on the uptake' or 'ready grasp' are more apt. haven't found any one word expression befitting.

Answer (score 6):

You can also say,

"He/she is very apt" which means able and also quick adaption.

For example, "He is very apt at his new job." New Job (Learning new things) based of SOME experience, school, education etc.

Comment: +1: She is an **apt** pupil: this usage of apt literally means "quick to lean". This the correct answer IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

This is only borderline English, I would say, since it's such an obscure word, but it's one of my favorites:

> TACHYDIDACTIC - Being taught rapidly or teaching quickly

No one will know it, but sometimes that's the fun of a word.

Comment: Goes well with "autodidactic polymath".

Answer (score 3):

I can't really think of a single word. I mean, "adaptable" is close, and most synonyms of "smart" could fit, but none have quite that specific meaning. Other related words are "polymath" and "autodidact" but again they don't have quite that meaning.

For short phrases there's "fast learner" and "quick study"

Comment: Autodidact should be someone who learns by himself, regardless of the speed, no?

Comment: Yes, that's why I said not quite that meaning. Being able to pick things up on your own implies being able to learn easily, but it's not exact. Similarly, polymath means you've mastered multiple disciplines; again that implies being able to learn easily but it's not necessarily quickly.

Comment: I didn't know polymath...

Answer (score 3):

> how about Aptitude

internet definition: readiness or quickness in learning;

Comment: What is the adjective form of this word? I almost wrote "apt" but I'm not sure that's right.

Comment: I believe "apt" would be correct.

Comment: Yes, but you can't just call someone "apt". It has to attach to a role noun, as in, "She's an apt pupil."

Answer (score 3):

I've most often used the word "adept" (not adapt) in your situation, although the book definition doesn't fit precisely, common usage (at least around here) seems to fit what you're looking for.

> — *adj*
>   1.    very proficient in something requiring skill or manual
>   dexterity
>   2.    skillful; expert

Answer (score 2):

Receptive is the English term used to describe the ability of learning or apprehending new things quickly. http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/receptive

However, according to the Oxford dictionary receptive alludes to the willingness rather than the ability to accept new ideas. http://live.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/receptive?region=us

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go for:

> **Assimilator :**  (noun)
>
> someone (especially a child) who
>   learns (as from a teacher) or takes up
>   knowledge or beliefs [syn: learner,
>   scholar]

Answer (score 1):

*Apprehensive* can mean 'quick of apprehension', and would seem to be exactly what you're looking for. Unfortunately, the 'fearful' sense is so common that your readers are likely to be confused. You could try *astute* or *acute*.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the words *adaptable* or *flexible*.

Comment: I'd argue that those words stress an ability to change and learn new things, but have no emphasis on speed. Slow learners can also be adaptable.

Comment: While "adapt" and "learn" don't quite mean the same thing, they are close and adaptable does include adapting quickly. "Slow to adapt" is pretty much the opposite of adaptable.

Answer (score 0):

How about **tachymath**?

http://blimix.dreamwidth.org/3726.html?thread=1422

https://books.google.com/books?id=HrwSBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA619&dq=tachymath&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uItJVd-sFobDggSP_IDQDA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=tachymath&f=false

Or **oxymath**?

http://www.longecity.org/forum/topic/3801-nikolas-lloyd-why-men-wont-dance/

https://twitter.com/rchbax/status/448413022655365120

Comment: 'I am officially adding "tachymath" to the English language.' English doesn't work that way.

Comment: You are a very earnest person.

Comment: In a democracy, the majority, not any specific individual, make the rules. Not, as Churchill conceded, that the majority necessarily makes the best decisions. But democracy usually works better than anarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Most people that I know would use the word 'bright' in the sense of being quick-witted or clever.