# What term means "one who enjoys learning"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term that means "a person who enjoys learning"? This term might be used to describe someone who:

- Is a self-motivated learner.
- Is curious, wants to understand many things.

I understand the term "philosopher" might be a good fit, in terms of its root words, however, the general population has an inconsistent understanding of this term, so I am looking for a more precise term.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a word in English that means "able to learn new things quickly"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23014/what-is-a-word-in-english-that-means-able-to-learn-new-things-quickly)

Comment: Someone who likes to learn and someone who learns well is two different things.

Comment: Someone who enjoys learning and knowledge for its own sake?  Probably the best word in the modern lexicon is "geek". :)

Comment: Aw, I was going to recommend **philosopher**, but as you say, it has taken on a different meaning in today's English.

Comment: aficionado, perhaps?

Comment: Searching a [reverse dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml) for *`enjoy learning`* or *`love learning`* returns [*`philomath`*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/philomath).

Comment: Does it need to be a noun? A similar question that permitted adjectives was marked as a duplicate of this one, and 'curious' would have been a good answer for that one.

Answer (score 35):

> **philomath**
>    [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Philomath) *- a lover of learning; a scholar.*
>   [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/philomath) *- a person who enjoys learning new facts and acquiring new knowledge.*

Comment: Also from [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/philomath): a person who enjoys learning new facts and acquiring new knowledge

Comment: 'Hermione' might catch on.

Comment: I seem to recall the term 'swot'.

Comment: @TimLymington Well, that's a British informality!

Comment: This word conjures images of someone having a love affair with mathematics.

Comment: The seventeenth-century façade of the old Shrewsbury School features a somewhat garbled version of Isocrates' line ἐὰν ᾖς φιλομαθής, ἔσει πολυμαθής: "if you are a philomath, you will be a polymath" ([1.18](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:abo:tlg,0010,007:18&lang=original)). ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrewsbury_School#Philomath_and_Polymath).) That surely familiarized many English lads of a certain class with the Greek word and by extension its English version.

Answer (score 10):

**Inquisitive**

*Eager for knowledge; intellectually curious*

That would answer the "[someone who] Is curious, wants to understand many things" part of your question.

Answer (score 7):

The specific word you want is not "Philosopher", which, as you note, has specific connections to the realms of metaphysics, ethics, and epistemology, but rather [**Philomath**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/philomath), which means exactly what you've asked for:

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Okay, you posted this a couple of minutes after I'd put up the same word. But if your typing is anything like mine it would take longer than that to input the text, so if anyone thinks it's plagiarism that seems unjustified. Anyway, I can't upvote the word on my own answer, so I'll upvote yours to cancel that downvote out! :)

Comment: @fumblefingers yeah, I typed an extra sentence and went looking for a better dictionary definition. And in that time, I got FGITW'ed. The downvote mystifies, but as a matter of policy, I don't acknowledge them generally.

Comment: I've just noticed that ***I*** have a downvote too! It's not that I feel "wounded" - but I'm a nosy so-and-so, and I'd like to know *why* someone doesn't think ***philomath*** is a good word here Particularly given the Collins definition @ermanen linked to, which even includes OP's own words "a person who enjoys learning".

Answer (score 7):

Rather than 'philosopher', there is an Ancient Greek word: '*philosophos*' - meaning 'lover of wisdom' (from *philein* ‘to love’ + *sophos* ‘wise’).

'Autodidact' is one possibility. Although it literally means 'self-taught', it does carry the connotations you're referring to, of self-motivation, intellectual curiosity beyond the bounds of formal schooling; enthusiasm for knowledge.

'Polymath' is another, although it refers more to depth and breadth of learning rather than the enjoyment thereof.

'Bibliophile' may be a little too specific, referring to the love of the actual artefacts of books, rather than necessarily their contents ...

... and 'bookworm' doesn't quite cut it, in this age where we get our information from so many other sources ...

If you are not averse to the idea of coining new words, how about **'cognophile'**?
 From the Latin roots: *cogno*, *cognoscere* - know, *cognitio* - knowledge, and the Greek: *philos* ...

This is a great question. I'm on the hunt now... I bet there's a German word for it, or something in Arabic or Hebrew ... '*cognitionis amor*' was a Latin phrase meaning 'love of learning'.

(This probably won't help, but I once had a boyfriend who called me a 'knowledge junkie', lol.)

Comment: Or of course, 'philomath'.
Dammit. how did I miss that?

Comment: I kind of like "polymath", even though it's not a direct hit on the requirements.  Describes those rare people like Steve Allen who seem to be skilled at everything.

Answer (score 4):

Epistemophiliac, someone who loves to acquire new knowledge : http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epistemophilia

Answer (score 3):

The term **[polymath](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/polymath)** means

> A person of wide-ranging knowledge or learning.

To the extent that you are trying to describe that person *before* she or he fully achieves this status, you could say **budding polymath**.

Comment: _Polymath_ is usually used in a narrower sense: to describe a scholar in earlier times who (as was often the case back then) was educated and discoursed in several distinct fields. Someone who was both a physicist, a mathematician, a linguist, and a medical scientist would be a polymath or polyhistor. However, someone who is extremely learned, but only within one field (like most researchers today), is not usually called a polymath.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The OP ask about someone who *wants to understand many things*.

Comment: Exactly—that’s why _polymath_ is not a very good fit, necessarily. Someone who enjoys learning and is motivated to understand many things doesn’t necessarily want to understand many things _in different fields_. They could be extremely interested in, say, physics and engineering, but not care an iota for philoshopy, linguistics, medicine, literature, etc. They would still be philomaths, but not polymaths.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to use this word for, you might also consider "*autodidact*". Strictly it just means someone who teaches themselves, the motivation for doing so is often an enjoyment of learning.

Answer (score 2):

Consider "bookworm, "culture buff," "[culture freak](http://www.thedolphinlmc.com/arts-leisure/2012/09/13/student-of-the-week-kelsey-woodrick/)," "[culture geek](http://charlestongrit.com/hunter-gardner)," and "inquiring mind."

> **bookworm**: a person who likes to read books and spend a lot of time reading **and studying**.
>
> [The public perception was of him as a culture buff, always visiting the ballet or a new exhibition, or hanging out with local musos like Moby or Lou Reed.](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=N70s2CgHlVUC&pg=PT246&lpg=PT246&dq=%22a+culture+buff%22&source=bl&ots=yuKiS1--En&sig=FVCUw4Rdb188TgDBiPy6ldmfRgw&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=2FhJU4XtBsjx0gXG04GwBA&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22a%20culture%20buff%22&f=false)
>
> [He is an **inquiring mind**. He wants to know the how and the why of the universe.](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1953IrAJ....2..138L)

Comment: Loving to read and loving learning, while *often **related***, are not synonymous.

Answer (score -3):

Swooping down to grab a few points is the "culture vulture"!

A "knowler", always on the lookout for "cutting-edge knowledge"? Take 'knowledge', cut 'edge', add 'er'!

Adders waiting to strike?

Comment: Being open, straightforward, and having a sense of humour is not the order of the day…

Comment: This particular culture vulture seems to have bitten off more than he can chew. (One problem with being a bird is you don't have any teeth! :)

Comment: Fangs, anyone? Or more beak-ering?

Comment: Aren't those verbal acrobatics a mouthful?!

Comment: Why do you feel the need to coin a new word, understood by nobody, when a perfectly good one, widely understood, already exists?

Comment: I would not always bank on it, but sometimes coining feels right on the money…