# Word for random knowledged person

Tags: single-word-requests

I want an adjective to define someone who is very knowledged of many things, even unusual stuff.

I know about polymath and its uses, but I was searching for a word more general, that could be used in this phrase:

> [Ken Jennings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Jennings) is a very _______ man. He won 74 editions of the Jeopardy! Game Show.

As exemplified above, it would be more general even being used in the context of trivia knowledge.

While [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163232/what-term-means-one-who-enjoys-learning) is a great question by itself, it has never been stated that the "person who is very knowledged of many things" actually enjoyed studying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What term means "one who enjoys learning"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163232/what-term-means-one-who-enjoys-learning)

Comment: Can you use Renaissance Man?

Comment: You could look up 'erudite' in a thesaurus and choose a synonym.

Comment: Renassaice Man is a term which fits more in the educational environment IMHO

Comment: *trivia pursuer*?

Comment: @Deltab to me a Renaissance Man would partake in activities beyond knowledge... can play guitar, able to do a few crafts well, speak multiple languages, know both physics and philosophy.  Broad knowledge alone wouldn't cut it.

Comment: Another related question (although not exactly a duplicate): https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247356/a-person-who-studies-random-things

Comment: To suggest a bit to other ELU readers, Jeopardy might have a category "Adele song titles" and a clue like "like a cannonball that fell off a ship" and an answer "what is 'Rolling in the Deep'" .  This sort of knowledge is definitely not attained from study, but more about "being a sponge of information" .  (actually "sponge for information" might be a nice informal vocabulary term")

Comment: A genius? What do you think?

Comment: Ken Jennings apparently has encyclopedic knowledge of anything and everything.

Comment: Very informal, but such a person is sometimes referred to as an "information sponge".

Comment: @Deltab I don't think the term renassaice man (or even renaissance man) does fit more in an ëducational environment. Quite the contrary.

Comment: What about "knowledgeable," which appears (more or less) in the question's title and in @etymologynerd.com 's definition of "adroit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **sage**

Ken Jennings is a very **sage** man. He won 74 editions of the Jeopardy! Game Show.

One of the meanings from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sage):

> wise, judicious, or prudent

2. **savvy**

Ken Jennings is a very **savvy** man. He won 74 editions of the Jeopardy! Game Show.

One of the meanings from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/savvy?s=t):

> experienced, knowledgeable, and well-informed; shrewd

3. **astute**

Ken Jennings is a very **astute** man. He won 74 editions of the Jeopardy! Game Show.

One of the meanings from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/astute):

> clever; cunning; ingenious; shrewd

4. **adroit**

Ken Jennings is a very **adroit** man. He won 74 editions of the Jeopardy! Game Show.

One of the meanings from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/adroit):

> cleverly skillful, resourceful, or ingenious

As already listed, *eclectic* and *erudite* would also work very well.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest

> [**eclectic** from Oxford living dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eclectic)
>   əˈklektik/
>   adjective
>
> 1.
>   deriving ideas, style, or taste from a broad and diverse range of sources.
>
> *"her musical tastes are eclectic"*
>
> synonyms:  wide-ranging, broad-based, extensive, comprehensive, encyclopedic;
>
> 2.
>
> PHILOSOPHY
>
> of, denoting, or belonging to a class of ancient philosophers who did not belong to or found any recognized school of thought but selected such doctrines as they wished from various schools.
>
> noun
>
> 1.
>   a person who derives ideas, style, or taste from a broad and diverse range of sources.

While the dictionary definition seems spot on, to my ear I would still single out "interests" or "knowledge" or "tastes" - Man of eclectic interests. Home decorated with an eclectic variety of styles.

For your sentence I might say:

> Ken Jennings is a <s>very _______ man</s> *a man with eclectic knowledge*. He won 74 editions of the Jeopardy! Game Show.

edit/note

the definition above suggests "encyclopedic" as a synonym, which could be another fine answer however I do not think that quite emphasizes the ephemeral nature of Jeopardy trivia.

for example...

Jeopardy might have a category "Adele song titles" and a clue like "like a cannonball that fell off a ship" and an answer "what is 'Rolling in the Deep'

Things like the names of popular song titles are learned from living, not study, and I think the word eclectic, which emphasizes variety of sources and their natures works well.

Comment: Does not _Ken Jennings is a very eclectic man_ works as well?

Comment: Yes, you can simply use "very eclectic man"  ... although without the reference to Jeopardy in the following sentence, people who do not know the definition of "eclectic" well might be unsure if he had eclectic tastes or prone to odd fashions etc. .. as eclectic is frequently used with 'tastes' these days.

Answer (score 3):

erudite

> characterized by great knowledge; learned or scholarly

[from dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/erudite)

Comment: I wouldn't call someone that was well versed in popular characters on TV shows, movie names particularly scholarly... erudite doesn't extend well to pop culture knowledge IMO.. it carries connotations of seriousness while, if I read the OP correctly, they want to emphasize that the person knows trivial things

Comment: @Tom22 thanks for having notice the "non-educational environment" I am trying to pass here

Answer (score 2):

A little obscure but **pansophic** could work well in your context and is probably directly related to the idea of "polymath."

From Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pansophism

> Pansophism, in older usage often pansophy, is a concept of
>   omniscience, meaning "all-knowing". In some monotheistic belief
>   systems, a god is referred as the ultimate knowing spirit. Someone who
>   is pansophical is someone who claims to have obtained omniscience.
>
> **It also has to do more specifically with pedagogic ideas of universal
>   wisdom (pansophia)**, as it occurred in the educational system of
>   universal knowledge proposed by John Amos Comenius, a Czech educator.
>   "Comenius's second great interest was in furthering the Baconian
>   attempt at the organization of all human knowledge. He became one of
>   the leaders in the encyclopædic or pansophic movement of the
>   seventeenth century" from the article on Comenius.

Answer (score 2):

Learned. He is a very learned man. (pronounced learn-ed)

> having much knowledge; scholarly; erudite:

<sup>[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/learned)</sup>

Comment: A good suggestion. I've added a dictionary definition and link to it to improve the answer.